# spConfig and where it can be defined and used?

Tags: product-attribute, configuration, store-view

Hey everyone so in my Magento File structure, in my

> app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

I have:

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
console.log("spConfig", spConfig);
```

And that gives me all the beautiful information I need! However why does it not show up if I call this exact same way on

> app/design/frontend/default/theme424/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

The interesting thing is when I turn on Template Path Hints in Developer->Configuation->Developer panel they are both on the same page and configurable.phtml is inside the wrapper known as the view.phtml

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into
`Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable::getJsonConfig()`. That's where the json gets generated.

Every product view gets rendered in `catalog/product/view.phtml`. Product type specific things like a configurable option dropdown, get rendered in `catalog/product/type/options/configurable.phtml`.

Why you can't call `$this->getJsonConfig()` in `configurable.phtml` is because:

- Template `catalog/product/view.phtml` has the block type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`.
- Template `catalog/product/type/options/configurable.phtml` has the block type `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`.
- The method `getJsonConfig()` is defined in `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable`

Answer (score 0):

The logic you are trying to use is bound to the block controlling the template file. If you really really need to use it in another template, which I don't see any reason for you need to change the block controlling that template.

You should note that the template containing the spConfig data also is specific for configurable products and might break your site if you use it for none configurable products.

I would advise against it but the block that can render the spConfig is: catalog/product_view_type_configurable